# Instagram news through API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is there any way to get [news feed](http://instagram.com/api/v1/news/) by API?

Now I can get it only if I set `sessionId` cookie, is there any another way? 
Maybe with access token?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to authenticate the user to instagram. As a result you'll get an access_token. You'll then have to use this token to query the api.